# EditText displayed nothing when resuming. (activity destroyed by android system)

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

My Activity is named BlacklistAddActivity.
  UI element:  EditText editText,  Button btn1.  When I click btn1, it will launch contact list activity and I can pick a contact from the contact list. Then send the contact info back to BlacklistAddActivity, and set the contact's name to the text1 by editText.setText(contact.name).

The problem is, sometimes, in contact list, if I do some operations: enter dialer from recent applicaton window(long press home key), and make a call etc...   As we know, the android will check memory to decide destroying the activity stack or not. If memory is low, it will destroy the background activities, including BlacklistActivity.
  Now, resume to contact list and pick a contact, resume to BlacklistActivity, it will be recreated. I can get contact's info correctly at onActivityResult(). Then, editText.setText(contact.name). Strange thing is: the editText shown on UI is still empty.

The following is my code: (not completely)

```
  public class BlacklistAddActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
static final boolean DBG = true;
private static final String TAG = "BlacklistAddActivity";
private static final String KEY_MATCH_CRITERIA = "match_criteria";

private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
private ListPreference mCriteria;

private static final int CONTACT_ITEM = 0;
private static final int LOGS_ITEM = 1;

private static final String NUM_PROJECTION[] = { Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER };

protected static final Intent CONTACT_IMPORT_INTENT;
static {
    CONTACT_IMPORT_INTENT = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    CONTACT_IMPORT_INTENT.setType(Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
}

private Context mContext;
private EditText editText;
private ImageButton searchButton;
private TwSoftkeyItem mLeftSoftkey, mRightSoftkey;
private AlertDialog mSearchDialog = null;

private InputMethodManager imm;

private boolean updateMode;
private String mNumber;
private int mMatchCriteria;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    initTitle();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreate()");
    setContentView(R.layout.blacklist_number_layout);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.blacklist_add_num_prefs);
    mSharedPreferences = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();
    mContext = getBaseContext();

    mCriteria = (ListPreference) findPreference(KEY_MATCH_CRITERIA);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    editText.requestFocus();
    searchButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.search_button);
    mLeftSoftkey = (TwSoftkeyItem) findViewById(R.id.skleft);
    mRightSoftkey = (TwSoftkeyItem) findViewById(R.id.skright);

    initValue();
    initEvent();
    imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            imm.showSoftInput(editText, 1);
        }
    }, 200);
}

private void initTitle() {
    String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("FROM");
    if (str != null) {
        if (DBG) Log.i(TAG, "initTitle() => from: " + str);
        if (str.equals("msg")) {
            setTitle(R.string.list_msg_block_num);
        } else {
            setTitle(R.string.list_call_block_num);
        }
    }
}

private void initValue() {
    updateMode = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("UPDATE_MODE", false);
    Log.i(TAG, "the updatemode is: "+ updateMode);
    if (updateMode == true) {   //from Edit
        mNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("NUMBER");
        mMatchCriteria = getIntent().getIntExtra("CRITERIA", 0);

        editText.setText(mNumber);
        editText.setSelection(mNumber.length());
        mCriteria.setValueIndex(mMatchCriteria);
        mCriteria.setSummary(mCriteria.getEntry());
    } else {    // from Add
        mCriteria.setValueIndex(0);
        mCriteria.setSummary(mCriteria.getEntry());
    }
}

private void initEvent() {
    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertDialogSearch();
        }
    });

    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean focused) {
            if (focused == true) {
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        imm.showSoftInput(editText, 1);
                    }
                }, 200);
            } else {
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    });

    editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                editText.requestFocus();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    mLeftSoftkey.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("NUMBER", editText.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("CRITERIA", mCriteria.findIndexOfValue(mCriteria.getValue()));
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    mRightSoftkey.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, null);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

    @Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        if(DBG){
            if(null != editText)
            Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState: Edit Text is: "+editText.getText().toString());
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        if(DBG){
            if(null != editText)
            Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState: Edit Text is: "+editText.getText().toString());
        }
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG, "onResume()");
    if(null != editText)
        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "onResume() Edit Text is: "+editText.getText().toString());
    mSharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    mCriteria.setSummary(mCriteria.getEntry());
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    if (mSearchDialog != null) {
        mSearchDialog.dismiss();
        mSearchDialog = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if (DBG) Log.v(TAG, "onSharedPreferenceChanged(), key: " + key);

    if (KEY_MATCH_CRITERIA.equals(key)) {
        if (mCriteria.getEntry() == null) {
            mCriteria.setValueIndex(0);
        }
        mCriteria.setValue(sharedPreferences.getString(key, mCriteria.getEntry().toString()));
        mCriteria.setSummary(mCriteria.getEntry());
        if (DBG) Log.v(TAG, "setValue: " + mCriteria.getEntry().toString());
    }
}

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("DONE");
                break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    String output = "";
    switch (requestCode) {
        case CONTACT_ITEM:
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult() => canceled");
            } else {
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(data.getData(), NUM_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
                if (cursor != null) {
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        output = cursor.getString(1);
                        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() => contact output: " + output);
                        if (Utils.isValidNum(mContext, output)) {

                            editText.setText(output);
                            if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() Edit Text is: "+editText.getText().toString());
                        }
                    }
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
            break;

        case LOGS_ITEM:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                output = data.getStringExtra("NUMBER");
                if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() => logs output: " + output);
                if (Utils.isValidNum(mContext, output)) {
                    editText.setText(output);
                } else {
                    output = null;
                    Utils.displayToast(mContext, getString(R.string.vip_msg_wrong_number));
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            imm.showSoftInput(editText, 1);
        }
    }, 200);

    if (output != null && output.length() > 0) {
        editText.requestFocus();
        editText.setSelection(output.length());
    }
}

private void alertDialogSearch() {
    AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ad.setTitle(R.string.title_search).setItems(R.array.dialog_search, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent;
            switch (which) {
                case CONTACT_ITEM:
                    startActivityForResult(CONTACT_IMPORT_INTENT, CONTACT_ITEM);
                    break;
                case LOGS_ITEM:
                    intent = new Intent("contacts.com.sec.android.app.dialertab.calllog.LogsListActivity");
                    intent.putExtra("OPTION", 1);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, LOGS_ITEM);
                    break;
            }
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    });
    mSearchDialog = ad.show();
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry, wait a moment, it prompt that my code is not formatted good and can't be posted.

Comment: Could anyone help me?  I think maybe it's the android's fault.

Answer (score 4):

Android does not automatically backup any data on your Activity when it gets destroyed. You have to manually back your data up before it gets destroyed and restore it when your Activity is recreated.

To backup your data, you must override this method. (It will be called before your activity gets destroyed.)

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putString("key", value); //save your data in key-value pair
}
```

To restore your data, you must override this method. (It will be called before your activity resumes.)

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    value = savedInstanceState.getString("key"); //retrieve your data using its corresponding key
}
```

Comment: But I can get the result from the Intent that send back from Contact list activity. For example: Intent data. data contains the contact's name And the name is set to editText. (please refer to the code). I log and found the value is not null. But why the editText can't display the string?

Comment: Perhaps I don't express my mind clearly. The key point is not the value of my EditText lost.  But when resuming, the text set newly is not displayed at all.   But it's OK if the activity doesn't get destroyed.

Comment: @andy: I updated my answer. If that's the case, you have to manually back your data up and restore it when your Activity resumes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it didn't catch the point.  You can refer to "onActivityResult()" in my code. There I get intent data from contact list activity. And then I have set EditText with contact's name stored in intent(the name is not null, I have check the log). And what's more, Actually, onActivityResult() is called after onRestoreInstanceState().

Comment: I know what you mean. and agree that android will not store data automatically if actvity is destroyed unexpected by android system.     More specific, Activity lifecycle when resuming(destroyed by sytem before): oncreate->onrestoreInstanceState()->onActivityResult()->onResume().   Actually, all ui is recreated and previous state is restored  in onRestoreInstanceState() function. then, I set editText a new value in onActivityResult().  The issue is, The value that I set    for editText is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

if your text is not set/displayed correctly you should take a close look at your `onCreate()`, `onResume()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` implementation.
so the answer from ***arci*** is what i would also answer in this case.

you say it is working the first time and also working if the `Activity` will not get killed. But when the `Activity` got killed and recreated it is not working. This sounds like you work on the **wrong reference** at some point.Especially when you use Listeners this can happen easily
You should go into debug mode and check your `Activity` and `EditText` **instance (via memory adress)** are the same/correct every time you access it.

I don't realy see the problem with your code but it has to be something like this.

Note: everytime you use `startActivity()`, go into landscape/portrait mode or something other calling `onCreate()` you may get a new `Activity` instance.

Note II: everytime `onCreate()` is called you get most likely call `setContentView()` what ends up in getting a newly inflated/created view. this means your `EditText` and other Views will be a new instance.